# Android NetUtils Wrapper: How do I add a SELinux Policy to use system/bin/ip-wrapper-1.0

Tags: android, network-programming, android-source, selinux, iproute

I am wanting to route traffic on the android app I am developing, though I am having trouble accessing the ip tables on the kernel. I am not sure if this is even supposed to be accessible for normal app developers, but I am trying.

According to Android's [network-stack](https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/hidl/network-stack#netutils-wrapper), one is supposed to use `/system/bin/ip-wrapper-1.0` to access the routing tables, for example, `/system/bin/ip-wrapper-1.0 route add table 1001234 224.0.0.0/24 dev wlan0` to add a table and route multicast traffic.

Problem: This is giving me a permission denied issue. According to the documentation above, I need to add the following domain transition rule in the SELinux policy: `domain_auto_trans(VENDOR-DOMAIN-NAME, netutils_wrapper_exec, netutils_wrapper)`

What policy do I need to add this to? Do I need to create my own policy? How do I connect this policy to my specific program?

I have scoured the internet looking for documentation on what policy to add this to or how to create my own vender policy, but there's no clear documentation on this (or at least not that I understand...). I'd appreciate assistance on how to do this, or a firm answer on whether or not an app developer (not an android developer) should be touching this.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by 'app developer' vs 'android developer' as there are: 1) developers of Android apps using Kolin/Java intended for app store delivery using the API defined by: https://developer.android.com/reference/packages 2) Custom ROM developers which may build system apps for their own custom ROM 3) apps intended to be run on a 'rooted' device which can access things that (1) cannot normally access. Generally if you are accessing routing tables those are system wide and for sandbox/security reasons only (2) and (3) can interact with them directly.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if selinux on android is the same as on red hat, but I suppose, the concept should be the same.

You will need to create your own selinux module. SELinux modules are "compiled" (macros expanded etc.) before "installed" (loaded to memory).

SELinux module is nothing more than simple text file with bunch of allow-rules (or macros wrapping those rules).
To compile a module you will probably need to find a tool that will do this for you, as the installation tools should exist on the system.

For example on Red Hat there is a package called `policycoreutils-devel` that contains `Makefile` specific for SELinux module compilation. You can call this makefile with you own definition of module as input and this will give you a compiled module- a .pp file.
Install this .pp file and you are good to go!

The thing you mentioned `domain_auto_trans` is a macro that will get expanded when you compile the module in which such macro is placed. Probably you can look up the insides of such macro.